# mybatis custom type handler without annoations

Tags: mybatis

I'm new to mybatis. I am trying to map a JDBC integer to a custom class. All the examples that I have seen on this have used annotations, is it possible to not use annotations and do this? Any example would be greatly appreciated.

Sreekanth

Comment: XML replace annotation in many contexts. Show code You trying

Answer (score 4):

It is definitely possible and is described in general in [Configuration](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html#typeHandlers) and in [Mapper](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#Parameters) sections of the documentation.

Define the handler first:

```
@MappedJdbcTypes(JdbcType.INTEGER)
public class MyClassHandler extends BaseTypeHandler<MyClass> {

    @Override
    public void setNonNullParameter(PreparedStatement ps, int i,
            MyClass parameter, JdbcType jdbcType) throws SQLException {
        ps.setInt(i, parameter.asInt());
    }

    @Override
    public MyClass getNullableResult(ResultSet rs, String columnName)
            throws SQLException {
        int val = rs.getInt(columnName);
        if (rs.wasNull())
            return null;
        else
            return MyClass.valueOf(val);
    }

    @Override
    public MyClass getNullableResult(ResultSet rs, int columnIndex)
            throws SQLException {
        int val = rs.getInt(columnIndex);
        if (rs.wasNull())
            return null;
        else
            return MyClass.valueOf(val);
    }

    @Override
    public MyClass getNullableResult(CallableStatement cs, int columnIndex)
            throws SQLException {
        int val = cs.getInt(columnIndex);
        if (cs.wasNull())
            return null;
        else
            return MyClass.valueOf(val);
    }
}
```

Then configure it in `mybatis-config.xml`:

```
<typeHandlers>
    <typeHandler handler="my.company.app.MyClassHandler"/>
</typeHandlers>
```

Now you can use it in xml mappers.
If you have a class

```
class SomeTypeEntity {
    private MyClass myClassField;
};
```

For querying the field configure handler in the `resultMap` like this:

```
<resultMap id="someMap" type="SomeTypeEntity">
    <result property="myClassField" column="my_class_column" typeHandler="my.company.app.MyClassHandler"/>
</resultMap>
```

For `insert`/`update` use it like this:

```
<update id="updateSomeTypeWithMyClassField">
   update some_type
   set
    my_class_column = @{someTypeEntity.myClassField, typeHandler=my.company.app.MyClassHandler},
</update>
```

for mapper method:

```
void updateSomeTypeWithMyClassField(@Param("someTypeEntity") SomeTypeEntity entity);
```