# Reading a JSON from DB with myBatis

Tags: java, json, mybatis

I have a column in DB I want to save it as JSON and retrieve it back.

My approach is:

I am saving it as `ClobTypeHandler` and trying to retrieve it as `ClobTypeHandler`.

I am using Mybatis, However getting below error.

```
Could not set property 'idType' of 'class package.abc' with value '{"idNum":"123","text":"ENCkk-KZJTmN8Mr5jEims0rssRow8xaAnkOtl0RQHDth1ByVtshI7zQebtcogOvYM-gNo15DwwPmduaufk03CteqRL03cRyrG4%3B","key":"}P]H73}AF}TGB$OIDCYVIIB+VW{4TR)I?U}_`_ZXP[UY$BJNXV{U~/@!F%+SVMFYT/2IAXIOPB"}' Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
```

Below is the java layer and DB detail.

```
class abc{

    private JsonNode idType;

    public String getIdType() {
         return idType != null ? idType.toString():null;
    }
    public void setIdType(JsonNode idType) {
        this.idType = idType;
    }
}
```

mapper.xml (Inserting to DB)

```
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER
    (<include refid="common_customer_insert_columns"></include>,id_type)        
 VALUES
    (<include refid="common_customer_insert_fields"></include>,<include refid="cc_customer_insert_fields"></include>,
        <choose> <when test="abc.idType !=null">#{abc.idType,typeHandler= org.apache.ibatis.type.ClobTypeHandler}</when>
                <otherwise>''</otherwise></choose>);
```

mapper.xml (while reading from DB)

```
<resultMap>
    <result column="id_type" property="abc.idType" 
        typeHandler="org.apache.ibatis.type.ClobTypeHandler" />
</resultMap>
```

sample JSON value I am trying to save and retrieve:

```
"idType": {  
       "idNum": "123",  
       "text": "ENh-KZJTmN8Mr5jEims0rssRow8xaADth1ByVtshI7zQebtcogOvYM-gNo15DwwPmduaufk03CteqRLaVwF0b3cRyrG4%3D",  
       "key":"}P]H73}AF}TGB$OICQ*DCYVIIB+VW{4TR)I?U}_`_ZXP[UY$BJNXV{@!F%+SVMFYT/2IAXIOPB"  
      }
```

Comment: any update on this, facing the same issue

Answer (score 4):

### To Save Data (Pojo Class) as JSON value and Read as POJO Class, we need to write custom TypeHandler

###### suppose we have an Employee class where config object need to save as JSON in DB and read as Config Object

Employee.java

```
public class Employee {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private Config config; //save as josn in DB
}
```

Config.java

```
public class Config implements Serializable{
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private String key;
        private String value;
        private String msg;
        private int referenceNumber;
}
```

JsonTypeHandler.java

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.apache.ibatis.type.BaseTypeHandler;
import org.apache.ibatis.type.JdbcType;
import org.apache.ibatis.type.MappedTypes;
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;


@MappedTypes({Config.class})
public class JsonTypeHandler extends BaseTypeHandler<Config>  {

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    
    @Override
    public void setNonNullParameter(PreparedStatement preparedStatement, int i, Config config, JdbcType jdbcType) throws SQLException {
        try {
            preparedStatement.setObject(i, objectMapper.writeValueAsString(config));

        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Config getNullableResult(ResultSet resultSet, String s) throws SQLException {
        if(resultSet.getString(s) != null){
            try {
                return objectMapper.readValue(resultSet.getString(s), Config.class);
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Config getNullableResult(ResultSet resultSet, int i) throws SQLException {
        if(resultSet.getString(i) != null){
            try {
                return objectMapper.readValue(resultSet.getString(i), Config.class);
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Config getNullableResult(CallableStatement callableStatement, int i) throws SQLException {
        if(callableStatement.getString(i) != null){
            try {
                return objectMapper.readValue(callableStatement.getString(i), Config.class);
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

MyBatis insert query

```
@Insert("insert into employee(name, config) values(#{employee.name}, #{employee.config, typeHandler=com.example.demo.image.JsonTypeHandler})")
    void saveEmployee(@Param("employee") Employee employee);
```

MyBatis Select query

```
@Results({
            @Result(property = "id", column = "id"),
            @Result(property = "name", column = "name"),
            @Result(property = "config", column = "config", typeHandler =com.example.demo.image.JsonTypeHandler.class),

    })
    @Select("select id, name, config from employee")
        List<Employee> getAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that without using the POJO:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode idType = mapper.readTree(<json-string>);
```

Comment: yes, but I need the POJO as there are additional fields the POJO consists along with this field

Answer (score 0):

`ClobTypeHandler` extends `BaseTypeHandler<String>` so it allows to set and retrieve value from database column as a `String`. When you use `ClobTypeHandler` like this:

```
#{abc.idType,typeHandler= org.apache.ibatis.type.ClobTypeHandler}
```

mybatis under the hood expects that `abc.getIdType` returns `String`, which it does. So far so good.

When you retrieve the value from the database the mapping used is:

```
<result column="id_type" property="abc.idType"
     typeHandler="org.apache.ibatis.type.ClobTypeHandler" />
```

In this case `ClobTypeHandler` tries to set `idType` property using `setIdType` setter and expects it to accept `String`. But the setter argument is `JsonNode` hence you get the message that type is incompatible.

To fix this change the type setter gets and do conversion from `String` to `JsonNode` in it:

```
public void setIdType(String idTypeString) {
     ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
     this.idType = mapper.readTree(isTypeString);
}
```

Note: you [can use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907929/should-i-declare-jacksons-objectmapper-as-a-static-field) static `ObjectMapper` to avoid creation it on every invocation.

A better approach is to create [your own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50179854/mybatis-custom-type-handler-without-annoations) `TypeHandler` for type `JsonNode`. It would do `String` <=> `JsonNode` conversion internally so you `abc` would be not polluted with this (unrelated) logic.

Comment: I am getting the below error after modifying my setter method with objectMapper:-                                                                  package.abc["idType"])" error="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException - Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token